# 4 digit current year function for mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm having some trouble with the following query:

```
SELECT horse_id, name, current_date()-born as age
FROM horse
WHERE died ='0'
AND name NOT IN('unknown dam','unknown sire')
ORDER BY horse_id;
```

The problem is that current date is yyyy-mm-dd the age column is only yyyy: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8nfS.png), so the age column is all messed up.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Obviously this only gives you an estimate of the horse's age. It may have been born in December and you run the query in January.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @ceejayoz:

```
> SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_DATE());
+----------------------+
| YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) |
+----------------------+
|                 2016 |
+----------------------+
```